# Python 3: timestamp to datetime: where does this additional hour come from?

Tags: datetime, python-3.x

I'm using the following functions:

```
# The epoch used in the datetime API.
EPOCH = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)

def timedelta_to_seconds(delta):
    seconds = (delta.microseconds * 1e6) + delta.seconds + (delta.days * 86400)
    seconds = abs(seconds)

    return seconds

def datetime_to_timestamp(date, epoch=EPOCH):
    # Ensure we deal with `datetime`s.
    date = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(date.toordinal())
    epoch = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(epoch.toordinal())

    timedelta = date - epoch
    timestamp = timedelta_to_seconds(timedelta)

    return timestamp

def timestamp_to_datetime(timestamp, epoch=EPOCH):
    # Ensure we deal with a `datetime`.
    epoch = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(epoch.toordinal())

    epoch_difference = timedelta_to_seconds(epoch - EPOCH)
    adjusted_timestamp = timestamp - epoch_difference

    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(adjusted_timestamp)

    return date
```

And using them with the passed code:

```
twenty = datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 4)

print(twenty)
print(datetime_to_timestamp(twenty))
print(timestamp_to_datetime(datetime_to_timestamp(twenty)))
```

And getting the following results:

```
2010-04-04 00:00:00
1270339200.0
2010-04-04 01:00:00
```

For some reason, I'm getting an *additional* hour added in the last call, despite my code having, as far as I can see, no flaws.

Where is this additional hour coming from?

Comment: Is it British Summer Time yet?

Comment: @msw Is that a disguised hint about timezones? ...It did start about a week ago, but I don't see where in my code it handles the timezone information or acts naïve as opposed to acting non-naïve?

Comment: yes, that was a hint, as I get the same results and am on daylight time too (in Python 2.6). I'm now munging through the god-awful datetime.tzinfo operation while I wait for the world to switch to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time

Comment: @msw Python's date-time API isn't as complete as I would have hoped.

Comment: @beau: +1 thanks for asking the right question at the right time, I was about to start using `datetime` heavily for cross-zone calculations and realize I was too naïve ;)

Comment: @msw What other alternative for Python is there though? `time` is too low level imo.

Comment: If you need cross-timezone arithmetic you'll need to bolster `datetime` up with `pytz`. Although note that even that doesn't quite conform to the expected `datetime` interface for dealing with timezones. Because as it turns out `datetime` is a bit crap. Personally I would strongly avoid doing time calculations with anything other than numeric UTC timestamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Ensure we deal with `datetime`s.
date = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(date.toordinal())
```

(That's chopping off the time-of-day completely, as ‘ordinal’ is only a day number. Is that what you meant to do? I suspect not.)

Anyway, as Michael said, `datetime.fromtimestamp` gives you a naïve datetime corresponding to what *local* time for that POSIX (UTC) timestamp would be for you. So when you call —

```
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(adjusted_timestamp)
```

you're getting the local time for the POSIX timestamp representing 2010-04-04T00:00:00, which of course in BST is an hour ahead. This doesn't happen in the return direction because your epoch is in January, when BST is not in force. (However your `EPOCH` would also be completely off if you weren't in the UK.)

You should replace both your uses of `datetime.fromtimestamp` with `datetime.utcfromtimestamp`.

It's sad that `datetime` continues the awful `time` tradition of keeping times in local time. Calling them ‘naïve’ and taking away the DST flag just makes them even worse. Personally I can't stand to use `datetime`, preferring integer UTC timestamps for everything (converting to local timezones for formatting only).

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your profile, you're in the UK. That means you're currently running on UTC+1 due to DST.

If I take your timestamp and run it through datetime.fromtimestamp on Python 2.6 (I know you use Python 3, but this is what I have), that shows me that it believes it refers to 2010-04-04 02:00:00 - and I'm in CEST, so that's UTC+2.

Running datetime.fromtimestamp(0), I get that the epoch is 1970-01-01 01:00:00. This then shows me that it is correctly adding only a single hour (since January 1st is outside of DST, and the epoch is midnight UTC on that date, it would be 01:00 here).

In other words, your problem is that you're sending in a time which has DST applied, but  datetime_to_timestamp treats it as if DST didn't exist. timestamp_to_datetime, however, applies the DST.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough Python to know how you would solve this, but this should at least give you something to go on.